# Android App, previously successfully loaded, has stopped working. Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I had an app successfully deployed (using JDeveloper) onto the emulator and it would run. Now all of a sudden it will not.

All i have changed was the emulators network settings, but reset them back to default after the app stopped loading, it still will not work tho.

I have tried wiping user data from the emulator and then deploying the app again, still it will not load. It was simply working then stopped working.

What could possibly cause this? Other apps i have deployed to the emulator work fine its just this one app.

Update: I have restarted everything many times

Comment: What does it show in the LogCat? Any sort of error/warning?

Comment: No it says deployed successfully, its just stuck in the Apps loading screen

Comment: Try running this on some device instead of Emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out JDeveloper was corrupted and that nothing was wrong with the emulator itself.

If anyone has the same issue I do I'd recommend re-installing what is deploying to the emulator.